# Windows 10 // v1809, Windows not maximizing active windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1809

I recently upgraded to Windows 1809 using a Lenovo laptop, and I'm facing an issue where, when I maximize a window by any of the following means:

- Click on the window's taskbar icon
- Using the `winKey + {n}` shortcut to maximize the nth window
- Using AutoHotKey's `WinActivate` and `WinSet,, top` functions

The window does not rise to the top. The window gains the keyboard focus, but is displayed below the most recently activated window. Or it does work, but it takes a 3-5 tries, which is *too many*.

The only way to activate windows that works consistently is the `winKey + tab` shortcut to view all my active windows, but I dislike this because it feels slow. Repeatedly restarting my computer or the Windows Explorer process has not helped.

Is there a solution for this? Is this a bug in windows v1809 that others are experiencing?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot by chance?  This behavior doesn't sound like a bug in 1809, which has been out for several months, and I certainly don't have the problem on any of my 1809 machines.

Comment: No, that would take too much time and effort, and it would have to be a GIF to capture what's going on. Also, there have been many issues reported on v1809 to Windows Explorer and taskbar issues.

Comment: Peace and love though, as always

Comment: Actually, AuthotKey's `WinActivate` does seem to work, so long as I have not just used the cursed taskbar to half-activate the window. For now, my workaround is to add a keyboard shortcut to activate each program on the taskbar using WinActivate.